# about flex httpservice issue

Tags: apache-flex

i create a class named xxHttpService that extends HttpService, and i override the construct method in which i set a custom header in order to send to local server to do things.Strangely, i cannot get the value from the header, it`s always A as i set it as B from the server side.  got any insight ? thanks in advance .

```
public class xxxHttpService extends HTTPService
    {
        public function xxxHttpService( handler:Function ){

            ****
            this.headers = {HTTP_USER: "Wking"};
            ****
              }
        }
```

Comment: If I understand, you're setting a custom header to one value in your HTTPService class; but the server always sees a different value in the same header?

Comment: are you calling the base class constructor in yours? (super() - I think..)

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of a mx.rpc.http.HTTPService has this heading if you'er not using the mxml version:

```
HTTPService(rootURL:String = null, destination:String = null)
```

If you're using the mxml version which is in the package mx.rpc.http.mxml.HTTPService you can't have a constructor with arguments.

I suppose you're talking about the first case.

Overriding that constructor would give you the class definition:

```
public class XxxHttpService extends HTTPService
{
   public function XxxHttpService(rootURL:String = null, destination:String = null) {
      super(rootURL, destination);
      ...
      this.headers = {HTTP_USER: "Wking", HTTP_PASSWORD: "Equeen"};

   }

}
```

Constructing this service

```
myService = new XxxHttpService("http://rooturl" , "myDestination")
myService.addEventListener(myHandler, ResultEvent.RESULT)
...
protected function myHandler(event:ResultEvent) {
   ...
}
```

should give you:

```
HTTP_USER:Wking
HTTP_PASSWORD:Equeen
```

in the http header when calling function send()

```
myService.send();
```

I'm not sure but if you should want to send them as POST of GET vars you should do this:

```
myService.method = "POST";//or "GET"
myService.send({HTTP_USER: "Wking", HTTP_PASSWORD: "Equeen"});
```